# read binary data into a vector using _read(), crashed at return

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to read a data from a file into vector. First I create and open a file and write vector v1 into the file, then move the file pointer to begin and read the data into vector v2, then print to verify the result. I can get the right result, but the program is crashed. I debug the program, the crash occurs at the return statement and the erro information is"0xc0000005: access violation writing at ...". I cannot figure out what's the problem. Could anyone have any idea to help me out? The test code shows below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <io.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <share.h>
#include <vector>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int outputfile;
    _sopen_s(&outputfile, "data", _O_RDWR | _O_CREAT | _O_TRUNC, _SH_DENYNO,      _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.assign(2, 30);
    v1.push_back(13);
    int num = _write(outputfile, &v1, sizeof(std::vector<int>));
    _lseek(outputfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    std::vector<int> v2;
    int err = _read(outputfile, &v2, sizeof(std::vector<int>));
    printf("%d \n", v2[2]);
    _close(outputfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do this with `std::vector` It has internal pointers, etc. that it uses for dynamic content management. You can't expect to just dump it as a raw memory image to a disk file, load it via raw-memory load into a different vector, and expect it to work. If you want to write the content to some image-target, you have to form a write/read *protocol* that does just that: writes the magnitude, then the objects, in a fashion that allows you to *rebuild* the vector using the associated read protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of a `std::vector` is typically a couple of member variables containing the size and the capacity of the vector, plus a pointer to the data. It does not contain the actual data of the vector itself.

To get the actual data of the vector use [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) or `&v1[0]` to get a pointer to the first element. And use the size of the vector, not `sizeof`.

Then for the reading, you need to preallocate the size of the vector you want to read into, and read into the *data* of the vector. Not overwrite the vector object itself.